# How can I examine if this limit exists?

Tags: integration, limits

I can't integrate $e^t/t$ so I don't really know how to examine if this limit exists:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-x}  \int_1^x \frac{e^t}{t} dt $$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: hint: integration by parts may be quite helpful

Comment: Take $e^{-x}$ in the denominator and apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Neither integration by parts nor L'Hopital's rule nor fancy computations are needed. Simply use the basic estimate saying that for every $n$ and every $x>n$, $$e^{-x}\int_1^x\frac{e^t}tdt\leqslant e^{-x}\int_1^n\frac{e^t}tdt+\frac1ne^{-x}\int_1^xe^tdt\leqslant C_ne^{-x}+\frac1n$$ for the obvious $C_n$. Hence $$\limsup_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}\int_1^x\frac{e^t}tdt\leqslant C_n\cdot 0+\frac1n=\frac1n,$$ holds for every $n$, QED. Exercise: Abstract the key ingredients of the proof to generalize the result to more general functions than $t\mapsto e^t$ and $t\mapsto t$.

Comment: @Did Why don't you put this as an answer? What is the "obvious $C_n$", $e^n$?

Comment: @mickep $C_n=e^n$ works, actually $C_n$ can be anything finite and $\geqslant\int_1^ne^tdt/t$, so I guess "obvious" refers to $C_n=\int_1^ne^tdt/t$.

Answer (score 3):

> **Theorem** (see Apostol's book Mathematical analysis, exercise 7.17) If $f$ increases and $g$ decreases on $[a,b]$, then  $$ (b-a)\int_a^b
> f(t)g(t)\,dt \leq \int_a^b f(t)\,dt \int_a^b g(t)\,dt $$

Since $e^t$ is increasing and $1/t$ is decreasing,
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_1^x \frac{e^t}{t}\,dt &\leq \frac{1}{x-1}\int_1^x e^t\,dt\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{x-1}\bigl(e^x-e\bigr)\log x.
\end{aligned}
$$
Multiplying by $e^{-x}$ implies that the limit exists and equals zero.

Answer (score 0):

$$ 0\leq \int_{1}^{x}e^{t-x}\frac{dt}{t}= \int_{0}^{x-1}e^{-u}\frac{du}{x-u}=\int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{x}}e^{-x v}\frac{dv}{1-v}\leq \int_{0}^{1-\frac{1}{x}}\frac{dv}{(1-v)(1+xv)}$$
but the last integral equals $\frac{2\log x}{x+1}$ by partial fraction decomposition, hence the limit is clearly $\color{red}{0}$ by squeezing.