# Trying to find bounds on this integral:

Tags: integration

I am trying to find a bound on this integral: $\int_x^t(u-x)^{H-3/2}u^{H-1/2}du$ where $t> x$ $0\le H\le1$ and $0\le x\le1$, but the kicker is that I need the bound to not depend on $x$. I am new to this kind of stuff, and I have tried a few tricks I know but they always seem to end up with the integral being undefined. It is important to notice that $H-3/2<0$, which is something that causes the problem to be tricky. Also the $x$ inside the integrand also makes the problem be tricky. It may not be possible as well, I am not sure.

Comment: Please show us one or several of those tricks you tried. Also, have you investigated convergence of the integral? It looks suspicious when $0\leq H\leq 1/2$.

Comment: It should converge, otherwise everything in this textbook where I got the formula is out the window. My basic approach at first(once again I am new at this) was that since $1/(u-x)$ will achieve it's maximum at the maximum value of $x$ possible(given that $u>x$), I followed that thought process a little and eventually got to it being less than this integral: $\int_{1+\epsilon}^t(u-1)^{H-3/2}u^{H-1/2}du$. The evidence seems to support this as a possible answer, but only for small values of $x$, and those values where this works very much depends on $H$. $\epsilon$ is small by the way.

Comment: I still think this may be a candidate for the right answer, but my reasoning is definitely not sound.

Comment: Which textbook is it? (And where in the book?)

Comment: It is from Stochastic Calculus for Fractional Brownian Motion and Application page 25, although I just lifted it out of the textbook for certain properties it contains and not really using it the same way.

Comment: They start out the section mentioning that $H>1/2$ on page 23. Then on page 25 they look at $H\leq 1/2$, indeed, but then, unless I understand things wrongly, the integral (2.3) is (in your terms) $\int_x^t (u-x)^{H-1/2}u^{H-3/2}\,du$, so as long as $x>0$ it is convergent. Looking at the factor in front, maybe one can also discuss the case $x=0$.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot there were two cases. Thanks for reminding me! I have fixed a $t$ and calculated the integral from several different values of $x$ and a greater $x$ always yields a greater integral, but I have no idea why that might be. That is why I chose 1 since it is the largest $x$ can get.

Answer (score 1):

Since you integral is not convergent for $0\leq H\leq 1/2$, I will below assume that $1/2<H\leq 1$. So, let $t>x$, with $0\leq x\leq 1$. The bound I give below will depend on $t$. I hope that is allowed (you don't say anything else). Also, it will blow up as $H\to 1/2^+$. I don't claim any optimality, but only give a bound independent of $x$.

**New solution**

As suggested by @JanG, it is easier to just integrate by parts:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_x^t (u-x)^{H-3/2}u^{H-1/2}\,du&=\frac{1}{H-1/2}(t-x)^{H-1/2}t^{H-1/2}-\int_x^t(u-x)^{H-1/2}u^{H-3/2}\,du\\
&\leq \frac{1}{H-1/2}(t-0)^{H-1/2}t^{H-1/2}-0\\
&=\frac{1}{H-1/2}t^{2H-1}.
\end{aligned}
$$

**Old solution**

As a start, we note that $u\mapsto (u-x)^{H-3/2}$ is decreasing in $(x,t)$ and that $u\mapsto u^{H-1/2}$ is increasing in $(x,t)$. Hence, (I've discussed this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1421764/how-can-i-examine-if-this-limit-exists/1421774#1421774) before)
$$
\int_x^t (u-x)^{H-3/2}u^{H-1/2}\,du\leq \frac{1}{t-x}\int_x^t(u-x)^{H-3/2}\,du\int_x^t u^{H-1/2}\,du
$$
The first integral is calculated to be
$$
\int_x^t(u-x)^{H-3/2}\,du=\frac{1}{H-1/2}(t-x)^{H-1/2}.
$$
Inserting this, we find that
$$
\int_x^t (u-x)^{H-3/2}u^{H-1/2}\,du\leq\frac{1}{H-1/2}\frac{(t-x)^H}{(t-x)^{3/2}}\int_x^t u^{H-1/2}\,du.
$$
The integral in the right-hand side can be bounded (just estimate with the maximal value of the integrand, which occurs when $u=t$)
$$
\int_x^t u^{H-1/2}\,du\leq (t-x)t^{H-1/2}.
$$
Hence,
$$
\int_x^t (u-x)^{H-3/2}u^{H-1/2}\,du\leq\frac{1}{H-1/2}\frac{(t-x)^H}{(t-x)^{1/2}}t^{H-1/2}=\frac{1}{H-1/2}(t-x)^{H-1/2}t^{H-1/2}
$$
But $x\mapsto (t-x)^{H-1/2}$ is decreasing, so it attains it largest value $t^{H-1/2}$ for $x=0$. Inserting this bound, we end up with

> $$
> \int_x^t (u-x)^{H-3/2}u^{H-1/2}\,du\leq \frac{1}{H-1/2}t^{2H-1}
> $$

**Comment**
If you would like to improve, one way could be to calculate both integrals after the first inequality to get that your integral is bounded by
$$
\frac{1}{H^2-1/4}\frac{t^{H+1/2}-x^{H+1/2}}{(t-x)^{H-3/2}}
$$

Below is a plot in the particular case $t=3/2$ and $H=3/4$. The green graph represents the true integral, the blue the one from the first integral estimate (i.e. the function in the comment above) and the orange the uniform estimate in $x$.

[image]